# Essentials Plugin config.yml: Prevent mob spawn not working?

Tags: minecraft-bukkit, minecraft-java-edition

I am using the [Essentials](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/essentials/) plugin for my Craftbukkit server. In the [`config.yml`](http://ess.khhq.net/cfg/) file, under the `prevent` tag, I set `creeper` to `true` in order to prevent Creepers from spawning:

```
# General physics/behavior modifications
prevent:
  lava-flow: false
  water-flow: false
   ...
  villager-death: false
  # Monsters won't follow players
  # permission essentials.protect.entitytarget.bypass disables this
  entitytarget: false
  # Prevent the spawning of creatures
  spawn:
    creeper: true
    skeleton: false
     ...
    villager: false
```

However, this does not seem to work, as Creepers are still spawning in my world... Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you got `EssentialsSpawn.jar`?

Comment: Yes, and it is loaded successfully.

Comment: Silly question: You have restarted the server after changing the config right?

Comment: Yup. I may have fixed it, but I'll need to wait and see when a friend joins my server to trigger mob spawns.

Comment: As a side note, you could be interested in [WorldGuard](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/worldguard/), which allows you to set creeper explosions to not destroy the landscape and buildings (and/or players), globally or in regions defined by you

Comment: @Zommuter, I'm aiming for more of a zombie apocalypse feel, so I'm getting rid of creepers and using Mobs to spawn lots of zombies instead. Thanks for the side note, though. Someone else might stumble on this post and need it.

Comment: @kevlar1818 I see. You might then be interested in WorldGuard's feature that you apparently can set different spawn points for different regions (http://wiki.sk89q.com/wiki/WorldGuard/Regions/Flags), I didn't test that though. Happy Zombocalypse!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I had the [Mobs](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/mobs/) plugin installed, and even though I wasn't doing anything with it (vanilla mobs were spawning), it seems to have overrided those settings the Essentials `config.yml`.

I fixed it by removing `Mobs.jar` from the `plugins` directory, reload plugins, then `/killall` Creepers.

I still plan on using Mobs, but the educational value here is that apparently you can't mix and match Essential's `config.yml` spawn settings and Mobs.